# unity update skipping calculation in a frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I'm Instantiating tiles as a path, on every four instantiating's tiles, they should start instantiating towards right, after four instantiating's, they go straight again.

to check this logic I, made a variable **spawnOffset** and incrementing +1 each frame.

if **spawnOffset % 4 == 0** change direction

but, i'm not getting a change in direction in regular intervals, when i debug, the frame skips and so is the logic

```
public GameObject go;
    public Transform Playertransform;


    public Vector3 tileSpawnOffset = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
    public int SpawnOffset = -3;
    private bool turnRight = false;


    void Update()
    {
        SpawnPath();
        ChangeDirection();
    }

    void SpawnPath()
    {
        if (Playertransform.position.z > SpawnOffset)
        {
            tileSpawnOffset += direction;
            Instantiate(go, this.transform.position + tileSpawnOffset, this.transform.rotation, this.transform);
            SpawnOffset++;
        }

    }

    void ChangeDirection()
    {
        if (SpawnOffset % 4 == 0)
        {
            turnRight = !turnRight;
        }

        direction = turnRight == true ? Vector3.right : Vector3.forward;



    }
```

[image: spawnOffset % 4 == 0]
and but when i tried with time instead

```
float time = 0f;
 void ChangeDirection()
    {
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        if (time > 1)
        {
            turnRight = !turnRight;
            time = 0;
        }

        direction = turnRight == true ? Vector3.right : Vector3.forward;

    }
```

it works perfectly fine. so, how could i fix it. I, don't want use time, i want to change direction exactly after 4 tiles spawned
[image: according to time]

Comment: It's interesting that you are comparing the float z-position to the int SpawnOffset.  Since it's not used in the Time version I don't believe you are having problems.  But start debugging it by checking the value of SpawnOffset and it's relation to the z-position.  I believe your issue may be there.

Comment: ```void ChangeDirection()
    {
        if (SpawnOffset % 4 == 0)
        {
            turnRight = !turnRight;
        }

        direction = turnRight == true ? Vector3.right : Vector3.forward;



    }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your always calling both  SpawnPath(); ChangeDirection(); everyframe if (Playertransform.position.z > SpawnOffset) is ever false twice in a row your turnright bool gets flipped regardless every frame your on a multiple of 4. You don't need to call ChangeDirection if you didn't spawn a new tile. if you just remove that call from update and add it at right after your increment SpawnOffset its probably going to fixe it.